# google bigquery inner join not behaving as expected

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table named `T` with the following structure:

```
Row date    a   b   c   d   e   f   g    
1   2.0051012E7 4.0 5.0 1.0 0.9 21.0    2.0170716E7 0.8
2   2.0131101E7 1.0 5.0 0.0 1.0 21.0    2.0170716E7 0.6  
3   2.0060908E7 3.0 5.0 0.0 1.0 21.0    2.0170716E7 0.7
```

and I have the following query:

```
select * from 
(SELECT date,max(a) as w FROM [T] 
group by date
order by date asc) as tableA
 inner  join
(select date,b from 
 [T]   ) as tableB
on tableB.date=tableA.date and tableB.b=tableA.w
order by a.date asc
```

Yet my results have:

```
Row tableA.date a   tableB.date b    
1   2.0040329E7 1.0 2.0040329E7 1.0  
2   2.0040329E7 1.0 2.0040329E7 1.0  
3   2.0040329E7 1.0 2.0040329E7 1.0  
4   2.0040329E7 1.0 2.0040329E7 1.0
```

Why do I have repeating rows? Isn't this what an inner join should eliminate?

Comment: You seem confused.  Inner joins do not eliminate repeating rows.  I can't imagine what you are thinking.  They are much more often implicated in exactly the opposite.  I would suggest that you ask *another* question.  Provide the sample data *and desired results*.  And, explain what you are trying to do.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I have results that map date to a max value. i then want to join to those unique dates and values the other criteria from those dates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend using BigQuery Standard SQL instead so there will be less confusions

> I have results that map date to a max value. i then want to join to those unique dates and values the other criteria from those dates

Try below for BigQuery Standard SQL

```sql
#standardSQL
SELECT entry.* 
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(row ORDER BY a DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS entry
  FROM `yourProject.yourDataset.yourTable` row 
  GROUP BY date
)
-- ORDER BY date
```

you can test it with dummy data as below

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH T AS (
  SELECT 2.0051012E7 AS date, 5.0 AS a, 5.0 AS b, 1.0 AS c, 0.9 AS d, 21.0 AS e, 2.0170716E7 AS f, 0.8 AS g UNION ALL
  SELECT 2.0131101E7, 1.0, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 21.0, 2.0170716E7, 0.6 UNION ALL  
  SELECT 2.0060908E7, 3.0, 5.0, 0.0, 1.0, 21.0, 2.0170716E7, 0.7 
)
SELECT entry.* 
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(row ORDER BY a DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS entry
  FROM `T` row 
  GROUP BY date
)
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: Thanks! I will test this. is it clear that I want date,max(B) and then I want to get the C,D & E which occur on each date entry that has max(B)?

Comment: that's exactly what it does :o)

Comment: just as sec  - max(a) or max(b)? from your code in question  - it looked as you wanted max(a)

Comment: if you need max(b) - you will need to change `a` to `b` in `ARRAY_AGG(row ORDER BY a DESC LIMIT 1)`

Comment: `SELECT entry.* 
FROM (
  SELECT ARRAY_AGG(row ORDER BY a DESC LIMIT 1)[OFFSET(0)] AS entry
  FROM  [T]  row 
  GROUP BY date
)` throws:  `Error: Encountered " "(" "( "" at line 5, column 19. Was expecting: ")" ...`

Comment: you should run whole query as it is in my answer  - with `#standardSQL` in first line. If still error - present exactly what error is!!

Comment: and you should use ticks to surround table name when you run in standard sql. see again carefully query in my answer ! I did small correction in my answer to hopefully help you to see this - so you should just replace yourProject.yourDataset.yourTable with your stuff

Comment: this is very helpful and a beautiful query. now i just need to do some homework to better understand.